# what is the meaning of $C^0[0,1]$ , $C[0,1]$ and $C^1[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Some difficulty to understand  the symbol

what is the meaning of $C^0[0,1]$ , $C[0,1]$ and $C^1[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Not sure about $C^{0}$ , but i guess the others are continuous function on that interval and continuous functions with continuous derivative on that interval, maybe the first is just continuous function and the second is continuous function with derivative.Nevermind just check here , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness.

Comment: $C[0,1]$ = set of continuous functions with domain $[0,1]$. Most likely $C^1[0,1]$ = set of functions with domain $[0,1]$ which are differentiable with continuous derivative. And $C^0[0,1]$ is often synonymous with $C[0,1]$, but maybe some authors use it to mean something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\ge 1, \; C^n(I) \;$ is the set of functions for which the $n^{\text{ th}}$ derivative $f^{(n)}$ is well defined at the intervall $I$ and is Continuous (at $I$).

for $n=0$,

$C^0(I)=C(I)$ contains all continuous functions at $I$.

Answer (score 3):

$C[0,1] = C^0[0,1]$ is the set of functions that are continuous over the interval $[0,1]$.

$C^1[0,1]$ is the set of functions that are derivable over $[0,1]$ and which derivatives are continuous as well.

$C^n[0,1]$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$, is the set of functions that are derivable (at least) $n$ times and where the $n$. derivative is in $C[0,1]$.

(Note functions in $C^1[0,1]$ are continuous since they are derivable)